How can add version suffix to end of some content of final build contents at Vite?
I am using Vite for building my REACT application. I am looking for adding a version query string at the end of some strings of final content of index.html and some image urls .
for example:
my index.html before building process is defined as :
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest">
  <script id="pwa:register-sw" src="./registerSW.js"></script>

Or in css files , the image url is defined as :
.class{
 background-image:url("/path/image.png");
}


An I'd like to add a suffix as version (at the end of all js and css sources and urls of images at css files).
The final index.html must be as :

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="./favicon.ico?v=version" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest?v=version">
  <script id="pwa:register-sw" src="./registerSW.js?v=version"></script>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-Dhfu8acq.js?v=version"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="./assets/index-C8LmPlD2.css?v=version">


and all image urls at css files be like :

.class{
  background-image:url("/path/image.png?v=version");
}


How can i do it ?

What for? Why not let Vite do it's normal checksum hash? It's the best way to avoid stale cached assets

My production does not have pipeline, and new files with new hash are not replaced with old ones, and need further actions to remove them.
